# How to make a for loop proceed outside the UI in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a for loop that sets a notification every minute of every hour of the day,

Code:

```
Future _showCollectionNotifications(int times, bool isHourly) async {
    var groupKey = 'com.ofo.app.collection';
    var android = AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'Id',
      'Name',
      'Description',
      groupKey: groupKey,
      setAsGroupSummary: true,
      channelShowBadge: true,
    );
    var iOS = IOSNotificationDetails();
    var details = NotificationDetails(android, iOS);
    String title = 'Collection';
    if (isHourly) {
      for (int id = 0; id < 24; id += times) {
        Time time = Time(id, 0, 0);
        String body = collectionLists[7].Collections[_getRandomCollection()];
        await randomNotification.showDailyAtTime(
            id, title, body, time, details);
      }
    } else {
      for (int id = 0; id < 24; id++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 60; i += times) {
          Time time = Time(id, i, 0);
          String body = collectionLists[7].collections[_getRandomCollection()];
          await randomNotification.showDailyAtTime(
              id, title, body, time, details);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

The problem with this is its freezes the app, so if can run the code in background or outside the UI in someway, then it'll help with the problem.

Thanks in regards.

Comment: Check out the [compute](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/foundation/compute.html) function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this case you should try [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_local_notifications) which will provide you with :

- Schedule a notification to be shown weekly on a specified day and
  time
- Schedule a notification to be shown daily at a specified time

example from the docs : **show notification every minute**

```
// Show a notification every minute with the first appearance happening a minute after invoking the method
var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
    new AndroidNotificationDetails('repeating channel id',
        'repeating channel name', 'repeating description');
var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics =
    new IOSNotificationDetails();
var platformChannelSpecifics = new NotificationDetails(
    androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.periodicallyShow(0, 'repeating title',
    'repeating body', RepeatInterval.EveryMinute, platformChannelSpecifics);
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me because i need to show the notification in specific minutes of the hour.

Comment: yes i got your idea it's a prayer time app which i did before using this concept